# SharePoint.Backbone Undefined Source -- JSON returns Empty

Tags: javascript, csom

I am working in SharePoint 2013 Foundation and I have a custom list named Properties that I am trying to use in a Backbone Application. The list contains all 90 of our properties and each property's corresponding Property Number. I am just trying in this first step to return the list's contents to the page.

I have included jquery-1.9.0.js, json2.js, underscore-1.4.3.js, backbone-0.9.10.js, backbone-sharepoint.odata.js and home.js in the head of my page (Home.aspx).

Here is the contents of home.js:

```
var Property = Backbone.SP.Item.extend({});

var Properties = Backbone.SP.List.extend({
    model: Property,
    site: '/',
    list: 'Properties',
    view: ''
});

var PropertiesView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: "ul",
    tpl: _.template(
        "<% _.each(properties, function(property){ %>" + 
            "<li><%= property.PropNumber + ' -- ' + property.Title %></li>" + 
        "<% }); %>"
    ),
    render: function(){
        $(this.el).html( this.tpl( { properties: this.collection.toJSON() } ) );
        $('#addressbooks').append( this.el );
    }
});

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    var properties = new Properties();
    var view = new PropertiesView({ collection: properties });
    properties.bind("reset", view.render, view);
    properties.fetch();

});
```

Nothing is getting appended to the page and when I debug through Developer Tools, I get an error of "Resource not found for the segment 'undefined'." Since this is the ONLY documentation for using the SharePoint.Backbone plugin (https://github.com/lstak/Backbone.SharePoint), I am hoping that the community can help me see what I am doing wrong.

Thanks in Advance!

-----UPDATE-----
The list is apparently OK. I ran this REST code and all of the properties appeared. The problem is I don't know how to turn this into a Backbone Collection without using Istak's library (which is the thing not working):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
//$('#addressbooks')
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://edrdbdev/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Properties')/items",
        type: "GET",
        headers: { "accept" : "application/json;odata=verbose" },
        success: function(data){
            $.each(data.d.results, function(index, item){
                $('#addressbooks').append( "<li><p>" + item.PropNumber + " -- " + item.Title + "</p></li>"  );
            });
        },
        error: function(error){
            alert(JSON.stringify(error));
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Is `var properties = new Properties;` correct? Should it not be  `var properties = new Properties();`?

Comment: The documentation had it as a Property and not a Method but I think it should be as you say. I made the change (and edited my question) but still get the same error and no content.

Comment: BTW, since this project is using ListData you should know there is a bug with task approval: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/64273/listdata-svc-and-task-approval

Comment: I can give you some jQuery functions that I use with ListData, but you should probably post on StackExchange regarding the BackBone question.

Comment: I would live to see your functions

Answer (score 0):

Usually I encounter this error when my JavaScript code is trying to access a list whose name is in a variable that is being used for the title/URL of the list but is in fact `undefined`. So looking in developer tools, you should be able to see on the network tab if you are attempting to access a URL or make a call to `http://servername/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('udefined')`. I suspect something is wrong with your Properties model.You'll need to investigate more with developer tools.

Comment: The Request URL is "http://edrdbdev/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/undefined" -- not good. I made sure that I copied the same Properties model accurately (substituting my list name for the example) so what I am doing now is creating a "Contacts" list and will use the actual code from the example to see if that works.  Thanks for helping!

Comment: I suspected from the error this was `ListData.svc`. I am sad to say I've seen that message enough I am surprised it's not in my nightmares yet!

Comment: I added the list (Contacts) and ran the EXACT code found in the documentation and received the same error. I was able to access the list via REST (I added my example to my question) but I need the JSON to be a collection in BackBone to feed our BackBone application.